# Install libdwarf.so on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, shared-library

How can I install `libdwarf.so` on Ubuntu? I get this error while running an executable file.

> error while loading shared libraries: libdwarf.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory.

Comment: /usr/lib/libdwarf-freebsd.so.3 is in package [libdwarf-freebsd-3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libdwarf-freebsd-3/filelist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after too many hours finally it's been solved. It goes like this:

1. Download [libdwarf-20130207.tar.gz](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/libdwarf/libdwarf-20130207.tar.gz/64b42692e947d5180e162e46c689dfbf/libdwarf-20130207.tar.gz)
2. Extract the archive and in a new terminal type:

   ```
   cd dwarf-2013-02-07/libdwarf
   ./configure --enable-shared
   make -j$(nproc)
   ```
3. If you need a 32 bit library (as in my case), just open the `MakeFile` and add `-m32` to `CFLAGS`

   ```
   CFLAGS = -m32 $(PREINCS) -g -O2 $(INCLUDES) $(dwfpic) $(POSTINCS)
   ```
4. At the end, just copy the `libdwarf.so` into `/usr/lib`

Comment: Thanks Petter Bajo. You answer with compiling the source and copying the library worked. I wanted to up your answer but I did not have enough points to do so. BTW, I also needed to install libelf-dev required for the compilation of the code.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this wasn't true when the question was asked, but in 2018:

```
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev libdwarf-dev
```

You might also be interested in https://github.com/aclements/libelfin.